# How to encrypt folders on my NAS with Cryptkeeper?

Tags: mount, nas, encfs

I use EncFS with Cryptkeeper to manage my encrypted folders (containing personal data files, bank, scans ...).

I would like to encrypt a folder on my NAS Synology but even when I have my NAS folder mounted on Ubuntu I cannot create an encrypted folder with cryptkeeper because the NAS isn't visible: I only have the local folders.

If someone have the solution, I would like to avoid the commande line, but maybe I can create a specific launcher for the folder? I would prefer Cryptkeeper.

Thx in advance.
D.

Comment: I seems that the synology is on NFS format cannot mount with cifs... I've try the syggestion on the Synology FAQ (http://forum.synology.com/wiki/index.php/Mapping_a_Network_Drive) but it reply me : mount.nfs: remote share not in 'host:dir' format Hmm.... I'll look over the web for a potential solution

Answer (score 2):

I think it should work if you'd [add your NAS to /etc/fstab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab) to have it permanently mounted.

---

In my case I added a drive connected to a Fritz!Box:

Open your NAS in Nautilus. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and copy the place without prefix(?), in my case //fritz.box/fritz.nas/WD-10EAVSExternal-01:

[image]

Create a place which should link to your NAS, i. e. /media/fritzbox:

```
sudo mkdir /media/fritzbox
```

Edit /etc/fstab:

```
gksu /etc/fstab
```

and add following line - adjusted to your settings:

```
# fritzbox
//fritz.box/fritz.nas/WD-10EAVSExternal-01  /media/fritzbox cifs    guest,defaults  0   0
```

Finish with mounting:

```
sudo mount -a
```

---

Then you should be able to see the NAS in Cryptkeeper, at least it works here.

Comment: I'll try that and give you a reply asap, I need to read before... Thank you for your fast reply, hope it will work :)

Comment: I just updated about how I did do that.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll do that with my next fresh install ubuntu LTS this week. I'll keep updated about the result.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the steps I use:

1. Create the EncFS folders locally with CryptKeeper, ie **.MyVault_encfs** on the
   desktop.
2. Delete the folder from CryptKeeper but don't delete permanently delete the data.
3. Move this folder to the desired location on the NAS
4. Import the EncFS folder in CryptKeeper via the gvfs folder, ie **~/.gvfs/myshare on myserver/.MyVault_encfs**. Your mount point must be outside the ~/.gvfs folder, such as **~/CryptKeeper-NAS/MyVault**. This is why we cannot create the CryptKeeper folder directly in the ~/.gvfs folder.  Also, please note that on 12.04 beta the folder is currently ~/.cache/gvfs but will likely be moved back.

The share will of course need to be mounted before the CryptKeeper folder.